# Taking logarithm of a variable in classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-engineering

I have a binary classification problem. Each data point has features $x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}$. I split my data into the training set and the testing set.
I have read that for right-skewed data, taking the logarithm can often help with the performance of the classifier. Suppose $x_{k}$ is the feature that is right-skewed.

Now my problem is even though $x_{k}$ is right skewed, some data points have negative $x_{k}$, so I cannot just take the logarithm. What should I do?

Here is what I have done:

In the training set I subtract the minimum of $x_{k}$ (the minimum in the training set) from each data point then take the logarithm.
In the test set I subtract the minimum of $x_{k}$ (the minimum in the test set) from each data point then take the logarithm.

I do this for every right-skewed feature. I calculate the skewness from the train set though (if a feature is right-skewed in the train set I subtract the minimum and take the logarithm in the test set without calculating the skewness of that feature in the test set).

I don't think this is the most correct way to do this. Should I use another transformation instead?

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell in general, since some algorithms may work regardless of scaling (decision trees for example), but did you try Box-Cox transformations after making data nonnegative?